# Let $k$ be an integer not divisible by $5$. Show that either $k^2-1$ or $k^2+1$ is divisible by $5$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Let $k$ be an integer not divisible by $5$. Show that either $k^2-1$ or $k^2+1$ is divisible by $5$.

Looking at this mod $5$ it seems that $k$ can be one of the form $k \equiv 1,2,3,4 \pmod{5}$. This would imply that $k^2 \equiv 1,4,9,16 \equiv 1,4,4,1 \pmod{5} \Longrightarrow k^2-1 \equiv0,3,3,0 \pmod{5}$ so $k^2-1$ is divisible by $5$? Similar reasoning could be used for $k^2+1$, but that wouldn't give any zero remainders so $5$ doesn't divide $k^2+1$ right?

I feel like I'm missing something since it seems that $k^2-1$ could also give a remainder $3$?

Comment: If $k^2-1$ gives remainder $3$, then $k^2+1$ gives remainder...

Comment: The simplest way to see this is to show that for these $k$ one has that $5$ divides $k^{4} -1 = (k^{2} - 1) (k^{2} +1)$. Now $5$ is a prime, so if it divides a product...

Comment: It is also important to note that if $r \equiv s\pmod{5}$, then $r^2 \equiv s^2\pmod{5}.$  Therefore, $(r^2 + 1) \equiv (s^2 + 1)\pmod{5}$ and $(r^2 - 1) \equiv (s^2 - 1)\pmod{5}$.

Comment: $4+1 \equiv 0  \bmod 5$

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't get so "sophisticated"- just do the calcuations.

(Edited so Dietrich Burde won't be annoyed with me!)

If k is not a multiple or 5 we have one and only one of
a)k= 5n+ 1 so $k^2= 25n^2+ 10n+ 1$.
$k^2- 1= 25n^2- 10n= 5(5n^2- 2n)$.

b)k= 5n+ 2 so $k^2= 25n^2+ 20n+ 4$.  $k^2+ 1= 25n^2+ 20n+ 5= 5(5n^2+ 4n+ 1)$.

c)k= 5n+ 3 so $k^2= 25n^2+ 30n+ 9$.  $k^2+ 1= 25N^2+ 30n+ 10= 5(5n^2+ 6n+ 2)$.

d)K= 5N+ 4 so $k^2= 25n^2+ 40n+ 16$. $k^2- 1= 25n^2+ 40N+ 15= 5(5n^2+ 8n+ 3)$.

Comment: Doesn't look nice. Why don't you use MathJax as in your other posts?

Answer (score 1):

We must have $k \equiv 1,2,3,4 \pmod 5$. Working$\pmod5$ one finds the following:

$k \equiv 1 \implies k^{2}-1 \equiv 0$

$k \equiv 2 \implies k^{2}+1\equiv5\equiv0$

$k \equiv 3 \implies k^{2} + 1 \equiv 10 \equiv 0$

$k \equiv 4 \implies k^{2} - 1 \equiv 15 \equiv 0$.